# С++ 11, std::function, неясность с параметрами шаблона

Tags: c++, c++11

В документации на [cppreference](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) указаны некоторые интересности:
Для начала определения простой функции и простой структуры, они нужны для примера, как леммы в теоремах:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int num) : num_(num) {}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};

void print_num(int i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Далее идет объявление:

```
std::function<void(int)> f_display = print_num;
```

Интересует меня параметр шаблона, я подумал: "это тип функции? ", так как еще ни разу нигде не видел круглые скобки в параметре шаблона.

Но далее идет еще одна интересность:

```
std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
```

метод `Foo::print_add` принимает на вход int, что это за параметр шаблона

Какой это тип? Т.е. какое общее название для таких типов? Там это не написано. И я это не могу нагуглить. Я понимаю что это объект назначения,  он содержит вызов функции (указатель на метод и аргумент), но какую роль тут играют круглые скобки? Я не могу просто основываться на логике, тут нужно прочитать.

Мне необязательно разжевывать, будет достаточно указать что гуглить чтобы знать об этом поподробнее, или просто дать ссылку на нужную литературу.

Comment: я не уверен что правильно отвечу. `std::function` - более удобная версия старых указателей на функцию. `std::function<void(int)> f_display = print_num;` `void(int)` - функция ничего не возвращает, принимает целое число. `std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add` эта функция нестатическая внутри структуры, для её вызова нужен экземпляр стуктуры, мы создаём указатель на функцию, который принимает эту структуру и число с делает вызов. грубо говоря `void f_add_display(const Foo& p1, int p2){ return p1.print_add(p2);}` у нас указатель на эту функцию. Там ещё про лямбды..

Comment: посмотри пример http://sitev.ru/post/54 - помогло?

Comment: @pavel в общем то, такие типы (параметры шаблона) очень схожи по синтаксису объявления указателя на функцию\метод. Но вот второй пример содержит сигнатуру с классом, это странно.

Comment: Отличный вопрос, не подозревал я, что `std::function` умеет хранить указатели на функции-члены. Отличный дизайн `std::function` со стороны комитета.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как мне кажется, вопрос всё же не столько по `std::function`, сколько по аргументу шаблона, у которого внутри используются круглые скобки.

> Интересует меня параметр шаблона, я подумал: "это тип функции?"

Да. Это именно тип функции. К тому же такая запись типа разрешена с незапамятных времен. Но использовалось в таком виде не часто. Чаще приходилось наблюдать тип "указатель на функцию", заданный обычно при помощи `typedef`. Например:

```
typedef void(*FP)(int);
```

В данном случае `FP` - тип, который есть "указатель на функцию, возвращающую `void` и принимающую `int`".

Одновременно можно задать тип `F` - "функция, возвращающая `void` и принимающую `int`":

```
typedef void(F)(int); // скобки вокруг F необязательны
```

При этом тип `F*` это будет то же самое, что `FP`. Т.е. везде, где используется `FP` можно использовать `F*`. Например:

```
void func(int);
FP fp1 = &func;
F* fp2 = &func;
fp2 = fp1;
```

Возвращаемся теперь к шаблонам. Для некоего шаблонного класса `C`:

```
template <class T>
class C { };
```

можно завести тип `C<F>`, или, аналогичный в интересуемой нас записи с круглыми скобками `C<void(int)>`. Несложно убедиться, что эти типы эквиваленты.

С принятием `c++11` форму со скобочками можно использовать и в `using`:

```
using F2 = void(int);
```

Тип `F2` будет эквивалентен типу `F`.

---

Скажу несколько слов по поводу второго примера из вопроса, т.е. уже относительно `std::function`.

Тип выражения `&Foo::print_add` есть `void(Foo::*)(int)` (указатель на функцию-член) и в явном виде он не может быть преобразован к `void(const Foo&, int)` (указатель на свободную функцию), который задан в качестве шаблонного типа. Однако реализация `std::function` допускает такое преобразование (это регламентировано Стандартом [(п.20.12.2 черновика)](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#func.require)), и т.о. справа от `=` может стоять как указатель на упомянутую функцию-член, так и на свободную функцию вида `void FreeFunction(const Foo&, int)`. В данном случае определение `INVOKE` (которое [присутствует в описании](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap#func.wrap.func-2) `std::function`) разворачивается либо в `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` (вызов функции-члена), либо в `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` (вызов свободной функции).

Comment: Может напишите, что для двух случаев(свободная функция и функция член), будет использоваться разная реализация и приведёте ссылку на стандарт(это есть в 20.9.2)? Всё-таки реализация и функционал довольно неочевидны и неплохо бы объяснить это более подробно.

Comment: @ixSci, хм... в Стандарте что-то написано про реализацию? Там же просто [шаблонный конструктор](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap#func.wrap.func).

Comment: Вот [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects#func.require) смотрите

Comment: @ixSci, может быть своими словами добавите в ответ, то, чего по вашему мнению не хватает?

Comment: Писать лень, я бы так ответ создал :) Но у Вас уже есть хороший ответ, который можно просто дополнить тем, что для двух случаев будет работать разная схема вызова. Почему я считаю, что это важно: в C++ нет механизма вызова вызова функции члена, если она не будет вызвана непосредственно для объекта, поэтому подобная запись `std::function` выглядит довольно «магически»

Comment: @ixSci, так я и предлагаю это в мой ответ добавить, а не в новый :)

Comment: Ответ Ваш — не люблю чужие ответы править, если только пару слов, а тут надо как минимум абзац написать.

Comment: @ixSci, кстати, насчет вызова функции-члена. Можно ведь и `auto f = std::bind(&Foo::print_add, _1, _2);` использовать.

Comment: Ну это уже будет явное создание функтора, а тут, судя по синтаксису, получается иллюзия, что функция-член будет вызвана как свободная функция с объектом класса в качестве первого аргумента, что в C++ не разрешено. До сегодняшнего дня, если бы я увидел такой синтаксис, я бы сказал, что он неверен, но в этом то и весь интерес заключается — комитет придумал довольно интересную штуку и именно поэтому было бы полезным включить это в ответ, я нигде не видел упоминания, что так вообще можно.

Comment: @ixSci, ну, не знаю. Код вызова будет вообще идентичный же. А инициализация через `bind` даже короче. Да и определение переменной `std::function` это ведь то же самое создание функтора. P.S. Вот уже несколько абзацев получилось в комментариях. Нет чтоб в ответ сразу добавить :)

Answer (score 4):

> Интересует меня параметр шаблона, я подумал: "это тип функции?

Это *callable object*, т.е. любая функция или функтор.

Если мы передаем в `std::function` указатель на нестатическую функцию-член, то мы можем указать объект-контекст вызова, на котором эту функцию требуется вызвать. (*Почти как* `call` *в JavaScript*)

Почитать можно [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/operator_func/)

> If the target is a pointer to a non-static member function, **it is
>   called using the** **first argument as the object on which the member is
>   called** (this may either be an object, a reference, or a pointer to
>   it), and the remaining arguments are forwarded as arguments for the
>   member function.

Comment: Нет, это не callable object, это call signature, что можно также назвать типом функции

Comment: @ixSci, вы правы, говорил о том, что под этот аргумент подойдет.

Answer (score 2):

Этот тип параметра называется "функция с заданным прототипом" aka "сущность, которую можно вызвать". [Англоязычный SO по той же теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)

То есть это вот `void(int)` внутри `std::function<void(int)>` - прямое указание - шаблон хочет кушать функцию с прототипом `void(int)`.

Далее. Чтобы функтор создался из нестатического метода, нужно иметь ссылку на объект и указатель на метод. Вот они:

```
std::function<void(const Foo&, int)> f_add_display = &Foo::print_add;
```

Первый параметр = константная ссылка на объект Foo, второй параметр - это уже первый аргумент метода Foo::print_add.

Фактически, нестатический метод класса отличается от статического тем, что в него неявным образом (нулевым параметром), передается ссылка на объект, для которого мы метод вызываем.

Когда мы захватываем метод в функтор, мы вместе с ним должны передать функтору и конкретный экземпляр класса.

Comment: Дополню, что константная ссылка на объект нужна постольку, поскольку функция-член `print_add` объявлена как константная.

Comment: Нет, это не называется «указатель на функцию», это называется «тип функции»

Comment: То, что вы говорите чем является первый параметр - это тёмный лес.  В стандарте старом сказано вот, что С++2003, 5.2.2 

There are two kinds of function call: ordinary function call and member function call -- (57) (9.3)....

57) A static member function (9.4) is an ordinary function. (С++ ISO/IEC 14882 2003-10-15)...

Comment: А вот описание реальности есть в замечательном докумнете - http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf , страница 19. ... In Microsoft compilers and 64 bit Windows, the this pointer is the first parameter, the return pointer is the second parameter, and all explicit parameters come
thereafter. In Borland and Gnu compilers and in 64 bit Linux and BSD, the return pointer is the first parameter, the this pointer is the second parameter, and all explicit parameters come thereafter (this order is compatible with C)....

Answer (score 1):

Тип функции существует с момента C89. Для выражения с типом функция разрешено только две операции - конвертирование в указатель на функцию и вызов функции.

> typedef void(*FPtr)(int);

В данном случае FPtr - тип, который есть 
"указатель на функцию, возвращающую void и принимающую int с соглашением по вызову её регламентированный соглашением о вызовах (calling convention) C++"

Ниже пример реализации собственного std::function для глобальных функций:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template <class T>
struct SmallWrapper
{
public:
    SmallWrapper(T theFunc) : func(theFunc){}
    T* func;
};

void test() {
    puts("test");
}

int main()
{
    SmallWrapper<void()> w(test);
    return 0'
}
```